# adding phpmyadmin to OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview

Tags: openshift

I am trying out  OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview for the first time.

I am trying to replicate the setup I have in Openshift v2
mysql, php and phpmyadmin.

Any suggestions on how to add phpmyadmin or something similar?
I cannot see it in the screen 'Select Image or Template'

Answer (score 0):

That's what I've done:

You need php app and mysql app:

In your php server do the following:

-> Go into de php Pod console and wget and unzip phpmyadmin

-> Go to the uncompressed phpmyadmin dir

-> Move config.default.inc.php to config.inc.php

-> Edit config.incp.php and replace configuration options with the data of the mysql pod

Now you can you can go to the url/phpmyadmin and everything will be working

The problem for me was to deploy the PHP and MYSQL apps. Too many errors and did have to try a thousand of times.